# chef - Gather details into one file from 3000 servers

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe

Iam quite new to the chef and iam trying to write a couple of cook books at this moment. MY goal is to write a chef cook book which will get the top 10 High Consuming process from 3000 servers. i have the cook book available but the problem here is i have to gather the details from all those 3000 servers into one file and send that as an Email.

How can i do that 
Please let me know if you need any more details on this

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 2):

This is not what chef is for. Cookbooks run on one node only. Better look for monitoring systems.